# Where is the password stored when used in PHP exec command?

Tags: php, linux, security

My php web page runs a command on the server:

```
exec("encrypt -pPassw0rd infile outfile; rm infile");
```

The server is linux.

Just ran a :

```
grep -R "Passw0rd" /
```

Is that enough to check if the password is not stored anywhere?

Comment: a) IMO it's not a good idea to use these PHP functions, I always block them in the PHP configuration. b) Why should the password be stored like that?

Comment: in a log file somewhere? bash history?

Answer (score 0):

The point here, is that input from the user, no matter the context, should never be trusted!

To combat these types of attacks, PHP provides two functions, escapeshellarg() and escapeshellcmd().

The escapeshellarg() function is designed to remove or otherwise eliminate any potentially harmful characters received from user input for use as arguments to system commands (in our case, the zip command). The syntax for this function is as follows:

The escapeshellcmd() is similar to its counterpart, except it will only escape characters that have a special meaning to the underlying operating system. Unlike escapeshellarg(), escapeshellcmd() will not deal with input that contains white space.

If user input will be used as part of the argument list for a system call, the escapeshellarg() function is always the better choice.

Hope that helps.

Fabio
@fcerullo

Comment: the password is not from the user it is system generated.